# Martian Terraformation

Tags: science-based, technology, near-future, terraforming, planets

### This have already been answered in several questions. See the comments for details.

I wonder what would it would take to bring Mars back to life. I've done some Googling and haven't found anybody answering the question 100%. Surely it's not a one-step process like bombarding ice capes with nukes, but combination of all ideas could actually work, and that's my idea:

1. First of all, warming up the core to provide an Earth-like magnetic field, or creating an artificial one with some high-tech orbital stations which would require a lot of energy; I believe it's possible.
2. Melting ice caps to create an atmosphere that would raise temperatures and escalate to a future domino effect and global Martian warming.
3. Planting some algae that could produce oxygen and in the future maybe strawberries.

I want to see your opinions and suggestions beacouse nobody has a complete idea of how to do it as of now.

Comment: You tried Google but have you look at the tag terraforming? http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2479/terraforming-a-very-cold-planet http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4147/what-can-we-do-to-mars-to-give-it-a-survivable-atmosphere  http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/how-long-would-it-take-to-terraform-a-lifeless-but-somewhat-earthlike-planet-usi http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11159/artificial-volcanos-on-mars-to-recover-its-atmosphere h

Comment: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/what-would-be-best-way-to-re-melt-mars-mantle-and-core-to-revive-its-magnetosph http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/19926/project-noah-blue-mars http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22190/how-can-i-get-soil-for-my-martians

Comment: Are you asking about this specific method, or ideas in general? If it is the latter, then I would say this is too broad. If it is the former, then the simple answer is that it won't be possible any time soon, even with a generous definition of "near future".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraforming Mars is the subject of Kim Stanley Robinson's 'Red Mars, Green Mars, Blue Mars' triology.

From wikipedia:

> "The book follows the characters across the Martian landscape, which
>   is explained in detail. As Russell's character infiltrates the
>   transnat terraforming project, the newly evolving Martian biosphere is
>   described at great length and with more profound changes most aimed at
>   warming up the surface of Mars to the brink of making it habitable,
>   from continent sized orbital mirrors, another space elevator built
>   (using another anchored asteroid that is dubbed "New Clarke"), to
>   melting the northern polar ice cap, and digging moholes deep enough to
>   form volcanoes."

Basically they use orbiting mirrors to concentrate the suns energy and blast the surface to release volatiles so as to form a greenhouse atmosphere. As you can see they also induce artificial volcanism.

Comment: Solar wind will quickly get rid of newly created atmosphere that's why i posted creating magnetosphere as 1st pt. That's why mirrors make none sense before magnetic protection ;/